# Android: Making a variable image

Tags: android

I would like to program an image that the user can press which will display another image when touched to give the user more information but then revert to the previous image after the user stops touching the image. I would also like to add vibration and a ding sound (which I have) when the image is touched. I looked into this but found someone else with the same problem who couldn't help - they said only one of the actions was possible. Help?!

Oh, and if you're feeling extra kind.. Is there a way to configure the amount of time the extra info picture stays when the user stops touching the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any coding at all before asking how to do it? Also, rather than asking how to do a whole project you should ask the parts you are having trouble on once you've actually attempted it...